# Symbol.asyncDispose is not defined on runtime

Tags: typescript

I have the following piece of code:

```
export function loggy(id: string): AsyncDisposable {
    return {
        async [Symbol.asyncDispose]() {
            console.log(`Disposing (async) ${id}`);
            Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(`Disposed (async) ${id}`));
        },
    };
}

async function foo () {
    await using k = loggy("asd");

};

foo();
```

This is my typescript configuration:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "display": "Node 20",
    "_version": "20.1.0",

    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2022", "esnext.disposable", "dom"],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "es2022",

        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": ["./src", "./tests"]
}
```

This is the error that I get when running it:

```
> ts-playground@1.0.0 main
> ts-node src/index.ts

/Users/eitan/git/ts-playground/src/index.ts:7
                },
                                            ^
TypeError: Symbol.asyncDispose is not defined.
    at __addDisposableResource (/Users/eitan/git/ts-playground/src/index.ts:7:45)
    at foo (/Users/eitan/git/ts-playground/src/index.ts:12:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eitan/git/ts-playground/src/index.ts:16:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/eitan/git/ts-playground/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/eitan/git/ts-playground/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
```

As you can see above I have defined the symbol on the object that is being returned from the function, however when I run the code I get an error that states that it is not defined.
I have checked that I am on the correct version of typescript and I have also provided my typescript configuration

Comment: How did you define `Symbol.asyncDispose`?

Comment: Well you're running the code in an environment that does not yet support the [*disposable* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-explicit-resource-management). Why did you add `esnext.disposable` to your `lib` setting?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add polyfills for the symbols
took it from the documentation:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-2.html

the fix in code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
Symbol.asyncDispose ??= Symbol("Symbol.asyncDispose");
```

Comment: A link to said documentation would be very helpful. Also, posting an image of a website is pretty bad for searchability.

Comment: Updated it to the link